# How can I enable/disable unobtrusive validation on show/hide via jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, attributes, unobtrusive-validation

Update:
What I'm asking is whether it's possible to remove validation rules which are inferred from Attributes on fields in my viewmodel, on the client side ONLY.

--

I am toggling the display of certain fields when a choice is made from a dropdown list.  I need to also toggle the validation.

ViewModel.cs:

```
public int ddlTypeID { get; set; }
public Dictionary<int, string> ddlTypes { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "msgRequired",
    ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Globals))]
public DateTime firstDate {get; set;}

[Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "msgRequired",
    ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Globals))]
public DateTime otherDate {get; set;}
```

Create.cshtml:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
       $('.optional').hide();
       $('#ddlTypeID').change(function () {
            var id = $(this).val();
            if (id == 1) {
                $('.optional').show();
            } else {
                $('.optional').hide();
            }
        });
    });
</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.ddlTypeID, new SelectList(Model.ddlTypes,"Key","Value",Model.ddlTypeID),Resources.Globals.msgType)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ddlTypeID)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.firstDate )
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.firstDate )
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.firstDate )
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label optional">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.otherDate )
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field optional">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.otherDate )
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.otherDate )
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

This works to hide/show the fields for otherDate - but how can I toggle the validation at the same time?  Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What does "toggle the validation" mean?

Comment: I think he wants to enable/disable it for the given fields.

Comment: Right:  if the fields are hidden, then I need to disable the validators.  When the fields are shown, then I need to re-enable them.

Comment: What about the server side validation? How do you intend to handle this? The server knows very little that you used javascript to show/hide some portions of your DOM. From the server perspective both fields are required in your current implementation. You should always first solve the server side validation problems before even thinking about client side validation. Client side validation is just a bonus that you can live without.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: Server side is done, pretty simple since I have the ddlTypeId.  The fields are not required in the database. I only need to handle the client side.

Comment: @chris, but the `ModelState.IsValid` will be false on your server when you receive the view model in your POST action, wouldn't it? How do you handle this case? You ignore the value of the ModelState.IsValid property and you roll your own custom validation in the controller?

Comment: I have a custom binder which handles the server side validation.  But that's not really relevant to this question.

Comment: It is not so simple if you want that it works in server and client side. You must write a custom compare validation for it. Start here http://www.concurrentdevelopment.co.uk/blog/index.php/2011/01/custom-validationattribute-for-comparing-properties/

Comment: @Zoli: If anything, I need the RequiredIf validator (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2010/06/04/conditional-validation-in-mvc.aspx) but I was hoping for something simpler.

Comment: @chris, you need more, that some out of box validator. You need to compare with other property value in server and client side. This behavior is little bit complicated, but not so many. You can write it in MVC 3, try to do it. Let me know if you need some more help.

Comment: @chris RequiredIf validator, that example is only server side, need some client side javascript code also - I think.

Answer (score 1):

It Works true.
But you need to call this code when you have hidden elements on form.
right code is :

```
function IgnoreValidationForHiddenElements() {

  $.validator = $("#formid").validate(
               {
                   ignore: ":hidden"
               });
}
```

or when you put on

```
$(document).ready(function () {
//Your Code
}
```

when you need this option when form Load.

Comment: He can't also call `.validate()` because Unobtrusive Validation already constructs and calls `.validate()`.

Answer (score 1):

I have this specific requirement and found that .Net MVC creates the "data-val" attribute on the control being validated. Give the control you want to toggle validation an id first:

```
<div class="editor-field optional">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.otherDate, new { @id = "ctlToToggle" )
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.otherDate )
</div>
```

Then change the "data-val" attribute on the control to true when visible and false when hidden:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $('.optional').hide();
       $('#ctlToToggle').attr("data-val", "false"); // Turn off validation on page load
       $('#ddlTypeID').change(function () {
           var id = $(this).val(),
               ctlToToggle = $('#ctlToToggle'); 
           if (id == 1) {
               $('.optional').show();
               ctlToToggle.attr("data-val", "true") // Turn on validation when visible
           } else {
               $('.optional').hide();
               ctlToToggle.attr("data-val", "false"); // Turn off validation when hidden
           }
       });
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

jquery validation actually does this automatically if you ask it to

```
$validator = $("#formName").validate(
{
    ignore: ":hidden"
}
```

I personally find JQuery validation to work a lot easier to use than MVC validation, but it does involve learning how to use JQuery validation if you haven't done so already.

(JQuery validate is a JQuery plugin that handles form validation entirely on the client side.)

edit: removed a bit of the parenthetical that, in retrospect, the OP obviously already knew.  My apologies.

Comment: This was the first thing I tried, but using jquery to show/hide fields sets display:none.

Comment: yes - and if you're using JQuery validate as your form validation, and set 'ignore: ":hidden"' as above, the validation will ignore all hidden fields. This doesn't work for MVC validation, however.

Answer (score 0):

If you put an 'id' on your input element (or use the MVC-generated ID), you can then use the [`.rules()`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/rules) function to remove the existing rules and save them to be restored later:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var savedRules;

  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.optional').hide();
    $('#ddlTypeID').change(function () {
      var id = $(this).val();
      if (id == 1) {
        $('.optional').show();
        $('#otherDate').rules("add", savedRules); // Restore saved rules
      } 
      else {
        $('.optional').hide();
        $('#otherDate').rules("remove", savedRules); // Remove the rules so they don't trigger
      }
    });
  });
</script>

@Html.EditorFor(model => model.otherDate, new { id = 'otherDate' } )
```